Validation not working on fields name ending with dots in angular
I'm creating dynamic fields
<input class="form-control-lg form-control" placeholder="{{data.DisplayName}}" formControlName="{{data.labelName}}" type="text"  maxlength="13">

this.fieldsData.forEach((ele, i) => {
  form[ele?.labelName]=new FormControl('',ele?.mandatory=='yes' ? Validators.required : []);
  this.FormGroup=new FormGroup(form);
..
}

on my HTML component displays an error message like this
 <div *ngIf="FormGroup.get(data.labelName) as control"> <div *ngIf="(control.touched || control.dirty) && (!control.valid)"> <p class="errorMsg" *ngIf="control.errors.required">This field is required</p>  <p class="errorMsg" *ngIf="control.errors.pattern">Please provide a valid email address</p>     </div> </div>

The issue is when the dot is there in the end in the field name validation is working but the error message is not shown.

please share a stackblitz where the issue happens

@NarenMurali https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-juuavv?file=src%2Fmain.ts pls check contact no. required validation message is not there

You can solve this error by using a different method of accessing the control. Obviously the problem is the dot. We can use the dynamic access method and using controls instead of getControl.
getControl(labelName: string) {
  return this.FormGroup.controls[labelName];
}

Full Code:
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {
  FormBuilder,
  ReactiveFormsModule,
  FormControl,
  FormGroup,
  Validators,
} from '@angular/forms';
import 'zone.js';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule, ReactiveFormsModule],
  template: `
    <form [formGroup]="FormGroup">
            <div *ngFor="let data of fieldsData">
            <ng-container [ngSwitch]="data.inputType">
              <ng-container *ngSwitchCase="'dropdown'">
                <select name="cars" id="cars">
                  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
                  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
                  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
                  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
                </select>
              </ng-container>
              <ng-container *ngSwitchCase="'textbox'"><textarea [formControlName]="data.labelName"></textarea></ng-container>
              <ng-container *ngSwitchDefault><input type="text" [formControlName]="data.labelName"></ng-container>
            
              


            </ng-container>
            <div *ngIf="FormGroup.get(data.labelName) as control" class="checkValue"> <div *ngIf="(control.touched || control.dirty) && (!control.valid)"> <p class="errorMsg" *ngIf="control.errors?.['required']">This field is required</p>  <p class="errorMsg" *ngIf="control.errors.pattern">Please provide a valid email address</p>     </div> </div>
            <label>{{data.labelName}} </label>
            
            </div>
            <button class="btn-submit" type="button" [disabled]="!FormGroup.valid" style="margin-top: 20px" (click)="SubmitDemo()">
                Submit
            </button>
    </form>
  `,
})
export class App {
  fieldsData = [
    {
      labelName: 'Name',
      inputType: 'textbox',
      inputValues: '',
      mandatory: 'yes',
    },
    {
      labelName: 'contact no.',
      inputType: 'textbox',
      inputValues: '',
      mandatory: 'yes',
    },
    {
      labelName: 'address 2',
      inputType: 'textarea',
      inputValues: null,
      mandatory: 'yes',
    },
  
  ];
  FormGroup!: FormGroup;

  ngOnInit() {
    const form: any = {};
    this.fieldsData.forEach((ele, i) => {
      const validators = ele?.mandatory === 'yes' ? [Validators.required] : [];
      form[ele?.labelName] = new FormControl('', validators);
    });
    this.FormGroup = new FormGroup(form);
  }

  SubmitDemo() {}
}

bootstrapApplication(App);

Stackblitz Demo

Use bracketed notation to avoid any issues with dotted variable ending names like below:
<div *ngIf="FormGroup.get(data.labelName) as control">
  <div *ngIf="(control.touched || control.dirty) && (!control.valid)">
    <p class="errorMsg" *ngIf="control.errors?.required">This field is required</p>
    <p class="errorMsg" *ngIf="control.errors?.pattern">Please provide a valid email address</p>
  </div>
</div>

Since you are following a reactive forms-driven approach in angular. Use FormControlName instead of name in HTML with square bracketed notation like below:
<input class="form-control-lg form-control" 
   placeholder="{{data.DisplayName}}" 
   [formControlName]="data.labelName" 
   type="text" 
   maxlength="13">

Follow it up with respective component.ts like below :
this.fieldsData.forEach((ele, i) => {
  form[ele?.labelName] = new FormControl('', ele?.mandatory == 'yes' ? Validators.required : []);
});
this.FormGroup = new FormGroup(form);


i have updated my code i have dot in my field name <input class="form-control-lg form-control" placeholder="{{data.DisplayName}}" formControlName="{{data.labelName}}" type="text"  maxlength="13"> ,data.labelName contains Contact no.

@user3653474 answer updated accordingly. Try using <input class="form-control-lg form-control"         placeholder="{{data.DisplayName}}"         [formControlName]="data.labelName"         type="text"         maxlength="13"> like this

Thanks i tried but if dot is there in field name i can't get the error message that this field is required

Can you provide a stackblitz?

Why on earth do your want to create a form with properties ends in dots?
You early fall in troubles.
I suggest add a new property, e.g. "name" and use some like
dataExtends=this.fieldsData.map((x:any)=>
  ({...x,
    name:x.labelName.replace(/[ |\.]/g,'')
  }))

and use dataExtends instead of data
